# Tablet/e-writer/pressure pad for writing with normal pen and paper, but electronic output

Tags: teaching, audio-video-recording

I would like to be able to create short 'video tutorials' or 'video lectures' where I draw on the screen and record my voice. I know that I can use [OBS software](https://obsproject.com/) to capture an application window and my voice to make the video and that is not the problem.

The question I have is about how to draw and have the image come up on the screen.

What I would like to do is to draw on a piece of paper with a normal pen on top of an electronic pressure pad, so I can see what I am doing on the paper and also record it on a screen.

My question is 'Is there any electronic writing device that will work with a normal pen and paper on top of it?' -- I am not asking what is the best way or the best device, I am just wondering if it is possible.

I have read this [question and the answers](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/40270/using-a-graphics-tablet-to-support-recorded-lectures), which is somewhat similar, but different because the question is just generally about capturing writing on a whiteboard or paper and not about writing on paper. I have also seen [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2853/device-for-writing-a-lecture-with-a-stylus-for-video-lecture-recording?rq=1), which is again less specific than the question here.

I am aware that one answer would be to have something like a document viewer with a camera above the piece of paper, but I would like to try to avoid that if possible so my hand does not get in the way.

So far I have only found either pressure sensitive pads to write on, where you cannot download the image like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QL11LWF).

Any suggestions very gratefully received.

Comment: I understand this is not an answer to your question, but what you are trying to achieve is *perfectly* solved by using an iPad with an Apple Pencil. You can even record the videos/animations directly on the iPad without having to go through your computer screen. There exists a great app exactly for that purpose: https://www.qrayon.com/home/vittle/ I understand you may have reasons why you might not want to go that route, but I wanted to bring it up because it is a truly excellent solution to the exact problem you are describing.

Comment: Also, just in case it is relevant: there's absolutely no need to get the "pro" version for this purpose. You can get the "regular" ipad (6th or 7th generation) and it will let you do exactly what you want. You might be able to find an older refurbished model (e.g. through Apple) if you want to save money.

Comment: @user2705196 - thanks for the very useful suggestion